# How do you type useImperativeHandle with typescript and materialUi Box

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```js
const Bx2 = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, {}>(
 function BoxRef(
   props: PropsWithChildren<BoxProps>,
   ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>
) {
   const boxRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
   useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       get box() {
          return boxRef.current
       }
   }, [boxRef])
   return <Box {...props} component={'div'} ref={boxRef}/>
})
```

Gives an error inside `useImperativeHandle` with

```
Type '{ readonly box: HTMLDivElement | null; }' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 278 more
```

am I missing some typings?